# Effcient weighted summation across pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

suppose with have two dataframes: df1 with some data and df2 with some characteristics. I would like to find a weighted sum per characteristics

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0.5,0.4,0.6,0.5],'B':[-0.2,0.3,0.9,1.2], 'C':[-0.7,-0.3,-0.9,-1.2], 'D':[1.2,1.3,1.9,1.2], 'E':[1,2.3,-0.9,3.2]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Category':['Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Gamma'], 'Size':[150,25,95,15,130]}, index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Goal is to get the weighted sum per 'Category'. I haven't found a better solution than using loops. Can someone think about a more efficient way? My code is below:

```
category = np.unique(df2['Category'])

result = []
tot_cat = df2[['Size', 'Category']].groupby(['Category']).sum()

for cat in category:
       
    df1_filt = df1.loc[:, df2.Name[df2.Category==cat]]
    df2_filt = df2[df2['Category']==cat]['Size']
    
    result.append(pd.DataFrame(np.dot(df1_filt, df2_filt.T) / tot_cat.loc[cat,'Size'], \
                           index = df1_filt.index, columns = [cat]))
    

final_df = pd.concat(result, axis = 1)
```

In that case, desired result for category Alpha (1st row) would be: (150 x 0.5- 0.2 x 25) / (150 + 25) = 0.4 and so on. Final df (rounded numbers) looks like this:

```
final_df = pd.DataFrame({'Alpha': [0.400,0.385,0.642,0.600],'Beta':[-0.7,-0.3,-0.9,-1.2], 'Gamma':[1.020,2.197,-0.610,2.993]},index=[0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Efficiency depends on the final use-case you have in mind: large df's or many unique categories? Did you have a look into `pd.pivot_table`?

Comment: @Marc - sure. I feel like using a for loop across different category is a "tedious way" of doing the job. If we have a case where we have thousands+ of different categories I am not sure it is the best way of doing it. I am confused on how to use pivot_table here since the data is on a different dataframe than the category. If I'm not mistaken pivot_table would be another way of calculating my "tot_cat" which is not the problem here as groupby does the job fine. But I'll have a look on this.